# Postfix negative is incorrect and communative

Tags: c++, stack, postfix-notation

So I'm evaluating `Postfix` expressions using a **stack**. The expression `10 6 -` reads as `10 - 6` infix and should equal `4`. But it doesn't, it equals `-4`. Worse, even when I try to reverse the code, it still equals `-4`. I'm not sure if this is something wrong with my stack, or the function calls, or some quirk of C++. However, if I store 1 popped value off the stack in a variable and then do the equation, it works fine.

Relevant code:
Stack class

```
template <class Item>
class stack {
private:
    struct node {
        Item item;
        node* next;
        node(Item x, node* t) {
            item = x;
            next = t;
        }
    };
    typedef node* link;
    link head;

public:
    stack(int) { head = 0; }
    int empty() const { return head == 0; }
    void push(Item x) { head = new node(x, head); }
    Item pop() {
        Item v = head->item;
        link t = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = t;
        return v;
    }
};

Evalutating the negative operation

    else if (argv[i][0] == '-') {
    stck.push(((-1) * stck.pop()) + stck.pop()); // A-B = -B+A
    // stck.push(stck.pop()+((-1)*stck.pop())); //A-B = -B+A
} // Both equations equal the same thing (Note I dont use both at the same
  // time)
```

This works

```
int n = (stck.pop());
stck.push(-1*n+stck.pop()); //A-B = -B+A
```

Comment: `pop` return and `Item`, what's the implementation of the `operator*` of `Item`, at least? It's much better a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a ["quirk of C++"](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/VSJ/SequencePoints/SequencePoints.html): the order in which the arguments in this specific expression are evaluated is undefined. It's weird how you get the same result twice, but you should generally not assume those pops are evaluated left-to-right!

From the linked article, section "Hidden Dependencies":

> x = f() + g() + h();
>
> Is there any doubt about what will happen?  At
>   first sight it appears as though nothing could go wrong here. The 3
>   functions will be called in indefinite order, the sum of their return
>   values will be calculated and an assignment will be performed.  But,
>   what if all 3 functions would access a shared static or global
>   variable that they read and modify?  We do not know in which order the
>   3 functions will be invoked and for that reason we would not know in
>   which order read and write access to the shared data would be
>   performed.  Again, another sequence point challenge.

Solution: use temporary variables.

Answer (score 0):

> `stck.push(((-1) * stck.pop()) + stck.pop());`

The problem is that's no sequence point between the two pop operations. This means the compiler is free to perform those operations in whichever order it wants. A compiler might choose to do the second `stack.pop()` first because it's easier. You need to make sure there's a sequence point. The easiest way to do that is with a semicolon:

```
subtrahend = stck.pop();
stck.push (stck.pop() - subtrahend);
```

There are other things besides a semicolon that can force a particular sequencing of operations. You could for example be very clever with the comma operator or the ternary operator. Don't do that. Just do the obvious think and put at least one of the numbers in a local variable.